# WPF Measureoverride trigger for parent for ContentPresenter

Tags: c#, wpf, layout, measureoverride

I have a deep nested WPF control like below

```
Custom Control
  -> Grid
      -> Grid
          -> Border
              -> Content Presenter
```

for some reason when I change the content of the content presenter, the measureoverride of the CustomControl is fired. I want to know if this is normal also how would you suppress the measureoveride to be fired. I have tried subclassing Content Presenter and overriding the framework metadata by setting the AffectsMeasure to false, but for somereason the flags are or'ed and are not set to false.

I already know the height and width and don't want the measure override to be called.

I have know way to know what is triggering the measure override.

Thanks. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I wonder if one of the other MetaData options triggers a measure pass. AffectsRender?

Comment: ContentProperty has only AffectsMeasure and there is no way to override it to false

Comment: Ah, that would explain it. So the answer is: yes, this is normal. Perhaps you can implement override `MeasureOverride` in your `CustomControl`, and call base.MeasureOverride() only if the sender is not your `ContentPresenter`.

Comment: How would you know the sender?. There is no parameter called sender on MeasureOverride.

Comment: You are right, of course. Sorry. I was thinking (without actually thinking properly) of an event handler. Can you capture the OnContentChanged event of the ContentPresenter and set it to handled before it gets to the CustomControl? Or the OnConentChanged event of CutstomControl to skip the measure when the even originates with the ContentPresenter?